# xamarin forms intent returns null exception for battery status

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

The following code gives me a null exception error when ispluggedin is called.   There is no diagnostic output other than the error.  I am trying to get the status of the android battery:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using ClockXF.Droid;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Texaco2))]
namespace ClockXF.Droid
{
    public class Texaco2 : Ipower
    {
        public Context context1 { get; private set; }

        public string ispluggedin()
        {
            IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ActionBatteryChanged);
            Intent batteryStatus = context1.RegisterReceiver(null, ifilter);
            int level = batteryStatus.GetIntExtra(BatteryManager.ExtraPlugged, -1);          
            string s = level.ToString();
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which lines causes the exception?

Comment: Did you check for null on the context1 object?

Comment: it is the context1 line that is causing the exception... what is the problem with context1?  How do I set the Context for RegisrationReceiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate Context is Android.App.Application.Context for RegisterReceiver.  Documentation on the battery is here:

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

The working code is as follows:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using ClockXF.Droid;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS; 

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Texaco2))]
namespace ClockXF.Droid
{
    public class Texaco2 : Ipower
    {    
        public string ispluggedin()
        {
            IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ActionBatteryChanged);
            Intent batteryStatus = Android.App.Application.Context.RegisterReceiver(null, ifilter);
            int pluggedin = batteryStatus.GetIntExtra(BatteryManager.ExtraPlugged, -1);          
            string s = pluggedin.ToString();
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```